# What is the link between homomorphisms and mutual information?

Tags: information-theory, morphism

Intuitively, there seems to be a link between the (kind of) homomorphism between two algebraic structures and the mutual information between two variables. However, since I'm not a mathematician, it's hard to see or formalize the exact connection. Anyone who can help me with this?

For example, if we'd take each variable to represent a set and its order relation, could we say that the very existence of a homomorphic map between the two would make their $ MI \gt 0 $ ?

And the other way around: would an $ MI = 0 $ between those variables make the map between them a random one?

Comment: What's mutual information in this context? Your question seems very "hand-wavy" to me...

Comment: @5xum Is "hand-wavy" necessarily a bad thing?

Comment: @QuinnCulver Well, in math, usually yes. Asking a question about a thing you haven't defined previously... there's nothing wrong with that in general, but in mathematics, it's not really the way we do things...

Comment: As far as I know, mutual information is a very well-defined concept in information theory. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @5xum Are mathematical ideas ever generated via "it seems like there's a connection between these two things"?

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at two examples.

In the case of vector spaces we have linear maps, or vector space homomorphisms. These preserve scalar products (1) and are linear(2).

Let $f: V \to W$ be a linear map.

$$f\big(\lambda x \in V \big) = \lambda f(x) \in W\quad (1)$$
$$f\big(x+y \in V\big) = f(x) + f(y) \in W \quad (2)$$

So we see that the operation of addition and scalar multiplication is preserved between $V$ and $W$.

In the case of groups, we have group homomorphisms. Similarly these preserve group operations.

Let $g: A \to B$ be a group homomorphism and $*$ the group operation.

$$g\big(a_1 * a_2 \in A\big) = g(a_1) * g(a_2) \in B.$$

So, in a sense, we can say the "mutual information" of the operations is preserved when a homomorphism maps an element from one object to another.

Comment: Thanks for the clear examples. Still, they do not make the link with mutual information very explicit. If the information of operations is preserved (preserving "mutual" information would be a rather strange notion, since preservation seems to be exactly what the mutuality is about) when a homomorphism maps an element from one object to another, isn't this the case with every homomorphism, since every homomorphism maps elements from one object to another with some structure preserved?

Comment: The "structure" is the information that we're talking about. In the case of vector spaces consider the element $(x+y) \ in V$. The homomorphism $f$ preserves this addition operation resulting in $f(x)+f(y)$.
In the case of groups, consider the composed element $a_1*a_2$. The homomorphism $g$ preserves the "composedness information" resulting in $g(a_1) * g(a_2)$.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. But is it than correct to say that EVERY homomorphism is (by definition) a map with MI > 0 ? And that a map with MI = 0 would be a random map?

Comment: What do you mean with MI?

Comment: MI stands for Mutual Information :)

Comment: A homomorphism preserves the operation that a structure has. How exactly are you quantifying Mutual Information? How would MI = 0 be a random map, from your perspective?

Comment: I'm not quantifying MI, it is by definition (in information theory) a quantitative concept. Homomorphism isn't, however, and my question is if the quality of being a homomorphic map can be said to be the range 0 < MI <= 1, while MI = 0 can be said to be the absence of any homomorphic map (and therefor the random map that preserves no structure whatsoever).

Comment: This is interesting. Mutual Information of two random variables is a measure of the mutual dependence between the two variables (from Wikipedia). Now, to answer the following: $$\text{For example, if we'd take each variable to represent a set and its order relation, could we say that the very existence of a homomorphic map between the two would make their MI>0 ?}$$
The way MI is defined, as an integral over a joint probability distribution of two variables, you would have to be really creative to come up with a way of letting this correspond to the set and the order relation as variables.